# react route function giving me blank page for my home screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm having some trouble wherein adding a route path to my app, it gives me a blank page on my HomeScreen. I add this line below to my app.js

`<Route path="/" element={HomeScreen} exact />`

Can you guys help?

**App.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main className="py-3">
        <Container>
          <Route path="/" element={HomeScreen} exact />
        </Container>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

HomeScreen.js

```
import { Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import Product from "../components/Product";
import products from "../products";

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Latest Photocards</h1>
      <Row>
        {products.map((product) => (
          <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
            <Product product={product} />
          </Col>
        ))}
      </Row>
    </>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap Everything between the BrowserRouter tag

```
<BrowserRouter> 
 --here--
<BrowserRouter/>
```

Comment: I had the same problem recently. I hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass JSX element in your Route as:

```
<Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} exact />
```

Answer (score 0):

Always wrap all your routes within the `BrowserRouter` and the `Routes` Components.
Also the JSX element itself must be passed in to your routes.

Please find the modified snippet below.

```js
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main className="py-3">
        <Container>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} exact />
          <Routes>
        </Container>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here how i use react-router-dom

index.js

```
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Provider>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>
  </Provider>
);
```

App.js

```
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App(){
   <>
     <NavBar />
     <Routes>
        <Route path="/">
          <Route index={true} element={<Home />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
   </>
}
```

Hope this will solve your issue